# How to measure the number of dropped UDP messages?

Tags: java, sockets

I have an assignment to measure the number of UDP messages dropped between client(s) and a server. The client and server are wrote in Java. The assignment is to measure how many packets are lost using varying sizes and numbers.

The assignment says the 'server' should count how many messages have been dropped. I don't see how that is possible because the messages are UDP-- therefore, how could the server even know a message was dropped?

Comment: You can put a sequence number in each client-sourced UDP packet that the server can keep track of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a datagram from the client, saying how many datagrams it sent so far, would reach the server, the server could calculate it, couldn't it?

Comment: Is there any built in functionality for sequence numbers? I started to dig around but it seems like it's done manually by writing the sequence before the message itself?

Comment: @Google The message format in UDP datagrams is up to the programmer, i.e. you ;). `Writing the sequence [number] before the message itself` is the indeed the solution.

Comment: What if that datagram was dropped?

Comment: @EJP Then you have to wait until a single datagram makes it to the server. The sequence number is attached to *every* datagram.

Comment: What if there is only one sent and it fails? Or what if there are a sequence of failures including the final one?

Comment: @Google Then you cannot, in principle, know how many datagrams were sent. If the client knows in advance how many datagrams it is going to send, you can include that number(and maybe an estimated time of delivery for the final message) in every message, too.

Comment: Thanks-- I am having some problems programming it but the logic and reasoning I am comfortable with. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Google Feel free to ask another question about programming details (preferably tagged `homework` so you won't get answers like "use package X/Y"). You'll need to write encoding and decoding functions that convert between `byte[]`(or similar) and numeric types like `long`.

Answer (score 1):

a complex way : you can create application level reliability.

receiver should reply with ack. if sender doesn't get ack in a timeout value, it is considered as dropped.

(added the term : complex)

Comment: But that would make it impossible to distinguish dropped message and dropped ACKs.

Comment: you are right, my idea is complex, creating an abstract tcp-like layer sholud be very expensive.

Comment: I believe this is how some telnet and ftp programs make UDP more reliable. It is pretty complex, but thanks for the post!

Comment: This is typically how I've seen it done with UDP-based protocols that need to track some measurable of reliability.